# Error logs frequency on debian web server

Tags: apache, logging, debian, frequency, vesta

my /var/log/apache2/domains/ error logs interval are too common, as seen below:

> [Tue Oct 24 16:00:06.273159 2017] [:error]
>
> [Tue Oct 24 16:00:06.273170 2017] [:error]
>
> [Tue Oct 24 16:00:06.273181 2017] [:error]
>
> [Tue Oct 24 16:00:06.273191 2017] [:error]

the result of this is error log of few GBs of log file after a few minutes of accessing the website that causes that error. Is there a way to make the error logs to be written less often?

Cheers

Comment: Fix the errors?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way for that. Although You can create a cron job to remove those big GB files everyday and restart apache as well